# download csv data from multiple URLs and combine to a single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, concatenation

I'm new to Python and trying to combine multiple 1-row DataFrames after downloading each via URL. I've been trying to use pandas pd.concat() without success. So far I get the individual DataFrames correctly, but combining them is not working using the following script:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from time import sleep
import numpy as np
import glob
import pathlib as pl2

count = 0

with open('tickertest12.txt', 'r') as my_file:
    newline_break = ""
    for readline in my_file:
        line_strip = readline.strip()
        newline_break += line_strip

#start the counter to pause the loop after x lines
        
        count +=1
        
        try:
        
            urls = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=" + line_strip + "&apikey=demo&datatype=csv"

            # Using pandas.concat() to append a row
                    
            #print(url)
        
            dfs = pd.read_csv(urls,header=0)

            big_df = pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index=True)
            print("this is big_df")
            print(dfs)
                    
        
                            
        except:
            print("Invalid Symbol",line_strip)


        if count == 3:
            sleep(0)
            print("pausing for 2 secs")
            count = 0
```

The .txt file is a list of ticker symbols: IBM, etc.

Assistance on what is missing or incorrect with the above would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need two DFs for concat to combine

change as follows

```
# define the empty dataframe prior to the line '`With open`', below `count=0`
big_df=pd.DataFrame()
```

```
big_df = pd.concat([big_df, dfs],ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thx for the feedback. When I run the script with that suggested change, I get "NameError: name 'big_df' is not defined"

Comment: for first time around, defined it an empty dataframe

Comment: Thanks! I added: big_df = pd.DataFrame()
  big_df = pd.concat([big_df,dfs],ignore_index=True) and getting Empty DataFrame
Columns: [{}]
Index: []

Comment: where you created the big-df?  it should be at the very top, before the for loop. is that where you have it?

Comment: Thank you! I just now moved it to the top, above the for loop----and that works! Last issue is removing the {} column at the end of the big_df DataFrame. I tried big_df.pop() and big_df.drop() without success. Any other ideas?